# getting Document property with key in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I have a model like this :

```
Class Store(Document):
    '''some fields'''
@property
def categories(self):
   '''get a list of categories'''
```

and I have a function like this that I can't change it and on this function I want to call the `categories` property of `Store`
the following function call a Document field like this :

```
class EmbeddedTables:
    def __init__(self, model, embededField, request, page_size=None):
        self.embeded_objects = model[embededField]
```

and I pass the parameters like this :

```
table = EmbeddedTables(g.user, 'categories', request)
```

and I can't call the property of `Store` and recieve `KeyError` 

How could I fix it ?

Comment: How is "categories" represented in the Store class? Is it an embedded field or a referenced property?

Comment: If `categories` is defined with `def` it isn't part of the document. You'll need to use `getattr` to access it dynamically.